# Story where human children are raised by robots because there were no adult humans

Tags: story-identification, robots

I read a number of books by the same author about human children raised by androids or human like robots because there were no adult humans

Edit - The androids acted like they were the actual parents of the children until some flaw/accident exposed them as not really humans.  In one I think the parent fell off a building to reveal electronics but take it with a grain of salt.  Then the truth was revealed to the group of kids, that they were the only real human beings and the androids were trying their best to replicate a normal human upbringing.

I got them from the local library late 60's early 70's.  As I recall they were towards the end of the alphabet as I can visualize getting them out of the back wall of the library which would be P's on to Z's if that helps!

Comment: This matches hundreds of novels. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question really needs more details; you should check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into the question.

Comment: The more information you can provide about the story (and when/where you read it), the more likely it is that someone can identify it for you. We recommend that you look at our Guide: [How to Ask a Good Story-ID Question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see what info you can add to this question.

Comment: No, I definitely remember reading this book. There were two children as the main characters, a boy and a girl. The boy was partially deaf in one ear. Every human was rendered infertile because of an unknown disease, the only symptom was a nosebleed. The two children did not know about this, they thought they were being raised by regular humans. Turns out, the robots were created to give parents "children", and there were versions to make them seem "older". ...

Comment: ... The children find out (I forget how but somehow all the robots get into "accidents" and need new parts), so the children set out to find new parts. They stumble into a cave that contains the parts, but it can only be opened by a human handprint (or is it only a robot handprint? I forget). There's also another robot involved that cannot speak, only flashes colors to communicate. I don't remember much, but I really want to re-read this book. If this description sounds familiar to anyone, please respond!

Answer (score 8):

What you describe has some things in common with a 1971 novel by Edmund Cooper called *The Overman Culture*.

I suggested this book as the answer to another question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135698/a-book-about-teenagers-isolated-in-a-school-with-robot-teachers-and-no-adults/135701#135701), and that answer gives more details about the book.

The main difference between *The Overman Culture* and what you remember was that it was only one book, not a series. Also the author's surname begins with "C", not late in the alphabet as you remember.

However it does feature human children being raised by androids who look like humans. It also features a human-seeming android being revealed to be a machine after a fall, but the android in question resembled a child not an adult. Eventually Michael Faraday, the young protagonist, realises that only those of his classmates who bleed are real humans - the rest of the children and all the adults in his life including his parents and teachers are androids. By the way, the children all have the names of major historical figures.

The environment in which the children were raised was not entirely a replication of a normal human upbringing. Anachronisms were deliberately introduced into the London setting, such as Queen Victoria co-existing with Messerschmitt fighters, in order to make the human children grow up to be questioning and curious. They were meant to realise that they were living in a reconstructed version of London, not the London of the history books.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this thread looking for a book where kids were raised by robots but the remembered line "Everything is for man" led me to it.  I read that back in the seventies but something must have stuck for me to remember that - It was *[Kuldesak](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5634367-kuldesak)* by Richard Cowper.

> Earth, 2000 years after the final holocaust which drove man deep underground; a ghostly, deserted planet peopled only by the diligent robots who, century after century, silently harvest grain which no man will eat.
>
> Up into this eerie world comes Mel, a questioning young Roamer who has disobeyed the Law which says he must never venture into or beyond the Lost Levels. Together with three companions, and a companion not of this Earth, Mel takes on the awesome task of freeing human beings from the tyranny imposed on them by their remote ancestors; of justifying the agonized cry of Barney as he died in a Forbidden Level: "I am a man! Everything is for man!"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you please add some more details, maybe a quote, from the book to show how it matches with children being raised by androids they don't know aren't human?

Comment: I recall this book fondly, but I do not think it is a good match for this Question. Society is in some ways run by robots in the novel, but my memory is that the remaining humans do not confuse the two.