# What is the in-universe reason for the anachronisms in "The Overman Culture"

Tags: robots, post-apocalyptic, the-overman-culture

The novel [*The Overman Culture*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?255933) by [Edmund Cooper](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?802) has been the proposed answer to at least three story ID questions, including [Story where human children are raised by robots because there were no adult humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225131/story-where-human-children-are-raised-by-robots-because-there-were-no-adult-huma/225454#225454), [Book about Shakespeare and Churchill as a robot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59647/book-about-shakespeare-and-churchill-as-a-robot/59662#59662), and [Looking for a sci-fi book about children being raised by androids with names related to literature](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170084/looking-for-a-sci-fi-book-about-children-being-raised-by-androids-with-names-rel/170133#170133).

Note, pretty much everything that follows is a spoiler for the novel.

In this novel, humans have destroyed themselves (I don't recall exactly how, and it is mentioned only briefly) leaving the earth populated by android robots.

The androids search for preserved caches of records of humans, and find several, but eventually one is found that includes living cells (maybe sperm and ova.) The androids use these to create a group of human children.

The children are named for famous scientists and literary figures, including Michael Faraday, Horatio Nelson, Ernest Rutherford, Jane Austen, and Emily Bronte. They are raised in an artificial contained "London".

This is populated by "adults" (who are all androids) including adults who the children are told are their parents, and adults who function as teachers and authority figures, including "Queen Victoria" and "Prime Minister Disraeli". There are also android "children" among the human children . The (human) children are told that there is war with Germany, and Messerschmidt  fighters are mentioned, along with other anachronisms obvious to the reader, but not nearly as clear to the children, as they do not seem to have been given accurate history texts.

An obvious out-of-universe reason for these anachronisms is to clue the reader in early that this is not our world, and that something very odd is going on. In-universe, why do the androids introduce these anachronisms? They do not seem to have any clear theme, purpose, or point.

Comment: I haven't read the novel, but I would hazard you may have answered your own question: "...androids search for preserved caches of records..."  Sounds like historical records will not be plentiful and perhaps a few volumes of history spanning 1800-1940(ish) are all the androids have to work with.  Many a science fiction tale (serious and satire) has spun a scenario where entire civilizations are built based on a few, or even one, slice of human history.

Comment: Could they be the equivalent of cosplayers?

Comment: @NomadMaker Could you clarify that comment please? It does not seem to make sense from my POV.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe that many of the robots take on the historical personas that they admire. Sort of like Pol Anderson's Hokas.